# using graphql github api to filter pr's merged between two dates

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

if you sign into https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/
and run this query

```
{
  search(query: "org:ruby is:pr merged:<2019-07-11", type: ISSUE, last: 5) {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on PullRequest {
          url 
          mergedAt
          commits(first: 12) {
            totalCount 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can get all the pr that were merged before 2019-07-11
I would like to get the pr's merged before 2019-07-11 AND after  2019-07-04

using `query: "org:ruby is:pr merged:<2019-07-11 and is:pr merged:>2019-07-04 "` does not filter. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `merged` condition:

```
org:ruby is:pr merged:<2019-07-11 merged:>2019-07-04
```

or use range syntax:

```
org:ruby is:pr merged:2019-07-04..2019-07-11
```

See [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/understanding-the-search-syntax) for additional details.